# Johnny Cash's Father

Tags: history, reference-request, johnny-cash

In the 2008 film directed by James Mangold *Walk the Line* it depicts Johnny Cash's father Ray as a jerk, and it also makes him look abusive to Johnny Cash and his family. I have found nothing in my research about this being true. Was Johnny Cash's father abusive and mean?